# ASP.NET App lifecycle hook after configure services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using the .NET6 GenericHost to create a web application having migrated through from previous versions.  Due to the breaking change documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#customize-webapplicationfactory we have a new problem where querying the database within the `Startup` class no longer works.

When creating Integration Tests it is possible to re-register DBContexts with a different type, e.g. InMemory contexts to replace a SQL Server context that would be used in production.

Previously the DBContexts will have been registered as InMemory Contexts prior to `Startup.ConfigureServices` being called, but now the `builder.ConfigureServices` is called *after* the `Startup.ConfigureServices` it is too late to replace them.

It does seem wrong to be querying the database during `ConfigureServices` so the plan is to refactor this process and move these calls to a later stage in the application.  This may be a combination of moving to Singleton Services which load as they are required, however one specific requirement is to check the database for some state which should block the application from starting up, so a hook which happens after `ConfigureServices` but before the app has finished starting up would be ideal but I am unable to find any details on what other startup hooks might exist.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the problem here. Why do you register an in memory context? What's preventing you from resolving your context and doing the necessary queries? It would help if you provided an example showing your situation.

Comment: You have used the wrong tags for your question. The asp.net tag is for the old .NET framework based web applications. Not ASP.NET Core. And similar ASP.NET Web API is for the old OWIN based framework, not ASP.NET Core. Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @mason - have fixed the tags.  Re the reasoning, I'll update as per that (in memory contexts are registered by integration tests to replace what otherwise get registered by the main app as SQL contexts)